# Do a dry-run of an Alembic upgrade

Tags: python, sql, database-migration, alembic

Sometimes `alembic upgrade head` may fail at runtime against my production database even though it worked fine against my testing databases. For instance, a migration might add a `NOT NULL` constraint to a column that didn't previously contain `NULL`s in my testing environment, but *did* contain `NULL`s in production.

When planning deployments, it'd be nice to able to check in advance of running a migration whether it will manage to apply cleanly. This is presumably impossible for databases that don't support transactional DDL (making schema changes in a transaction) like MySQL, but ought to be possible in principle for databases that *do* support transactional DDL, like PostgreSQL; Alembic could just try performing the upgrade in a transaction, then roll it back.

(One caveat: this is an imperfect solution, since PostgreSQL permits some constraints to be `DEFERRED`, meaning they aren't checked until you commit. A dry-run that checks these is, I suppose, impossible without creating a copy of the database. But still, doing the DDL-and-rollback approach is better than nothing.)

Does Alembic have any support for such functionality? If not, is there some hacky way to achieve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple trick to allow this is to inject a conditional rollback into the `run_migrations_online` function in `env.py` that fires only when some flag is present indicating that we want a dry-run.

In case yours is already modified, recall the default implementation of the `run_migrations_online` function created by `alembic init` looks like this:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

Note that:

- the `__enter__` method of `context.begin_transaction()` - which we're already calling in the default implementation - gives us a transaction object with a `rollback()` method, if the backend uses transactional DDL, or if transactional ddl is forced on using the transactional_ddl flag, and
- our `context` object has a [`get_x_argument`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=compare_server_default#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.get_x_argument) method we can use to support passing custom arguments to the `alembic` command.

Thus, with the following small change (everything below is the same besides the addition of `as transaction` plus the final three lines) we can have our dry-run functionality:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,

        # Ensure the context will create a transaction
        # for backends that don't normally use transactional DDL.
        # Note that ROLLBACK will not roll back DDL structures
        # on databases such as MySQL, as well as with the SQLite
        # Python driver's default settings.
        transactional_ddl=True,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )
        with context.begin_transaction() as transaction:
            context.run_migrations()
            if 'dry-run' in context.get_x_argument():
                print('Dry-run succeeded; now rolling back transaction...')
                transaction.rollback()
```

Now, to do a dry-run, do:

```
alembic -x dry-run upgrade head
```

and to do a real run, just do:

```
alembic upgrade head
```

like before.

Comment: @zzzeek I am confused by the `transactional_ddl=True` parameter introduced in your edit. Per https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.transactional_ddl, this parameter *"defaults to whether or not the dialect in use supports it"*. So setting it explicitly to `True` will only have an effect in dialects that *don't* support it? What will the effect *be*? I guess it will cause Alembic to try to run DDL in a transaction anyway, and so crash? And you figure that this is better than unexpectedly doing the DDL for real?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. it works for when I use
`alembic -x connection=dbname -x dry_run=True upgrade head`
if just passing in dry_run it failed
`alembic -x connection_spec=MatsDBDev -x dry_run upgrade head`
how can I use dry_run without passing in True?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own alembic config, script directory, and environment context. Critically this should have an already-created connection passed to it, which you have the ability to roll back after you're completed the dry-run.

```
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
session = Session(bind=engine)
try:
    alembic_config = AlembicConfig(config_args={...})
    alembic_config.attributes.update({"connection": session.connection()})
    script_directory = ScriptDirectory.from_config(alembic_config)
    env_context = EnvironmentContext(
        alembic_config,
        script_directory,
        fn=lambda rev, context: script_directory._upgrade_revs("head", rev),
        as_sql=False,
    )
    env_context.configure(connection=session.connection())
    env_context.run_migrations()

finally:
    session.rollback()
    session.close()
```

Comment: This probably works, but I was a little uneasy about the fact that it's not reading the alembic.ini config nor setting up the context object in *exactly* the same way that it would be set up when running the real migrations. For that reason, I scratched my head for a bit until I realised that a simpler solution is available - I'm about to post my own answer.